# LineBreak in Array which is in Object Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have an Object of node in which there is an array of text i want to print node.text with line break in mapping function

```
   {this.state.nodes.map((node, index) => {

         return(
          <div
                 key={index}
                 className={'node ' + node.className}
                 id={node.id}
                 ref={nodes => this.refs.nodes[index] = nodes}
                 style={node.style}
                 onClick={this.activeElem}

             >

         {node.text}

        })}
```

it is printing an entire object i have tried \n and 
 both are not working how can i show it with LineBreak

This is mine Json object

here is the screenshot of my json object

https://gyazo.com/8da374e8cbdaf85c7516b27c415eab9c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try this `{node.text}<br/>`
or insert it inside **div** element 
`<div>{node.text}</div>`

if you need to linebreak the content of the array you can do the following :

```
 {node.text.map(item => (
              <div >
                 {item}
              </div>
            ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your div in a React Fragment and put a `<br>` after every div.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML you can't make Line Breaks via \n. There are serveral ways to do line breaks with HTML and CSS, the easiest one is the `<br>` tag

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br

You could map over the array and add an 
 tag on every iteration.